# Doing LDA (NLP task): Does it make sense to use tf-idf vectors?

Tags: tfidf, lda

Most implementations that I've seen of LDA seem to use simple word counts when giving the document-term frequency matrix.

What would happen if we were to give the tf-idf matrix instead of a simple word count matrix?